# What should you do with a correct answer to a different question?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979782/analyze-content-type-in-java) asks "Given a MIME type, how can I determine whether it's for text or binary content, without analyzing the content?"

[The current only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979941/106104) says how to guess the MIME type of the contents of a file. It is not wrong, but it also does not answer the question.

As a user who saw this answer while browsing questions, what should I do with this answer - downvote it? Flag it as "not an answer"?

Comment: You can downvote it if you want, and comment on it as well. If the answer really does not help the asker at all you can report it. Feel free to edit the answer so it answers the question as well.